# Ejecutar un método de una función a través de url en php

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Estimados

tengo una consulta, resulta que estoy trabajando con php en poo mvc, y quiero pasar los datos a traves de url al controlador y quiero desencadenar el método guardar de una clase, cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo? mi codigo es el siguiente

formulario vista.php

```
<form action="../Controller/ProjectoController.php" method="post" name="crearproyecto" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-3 ">
                <label>Nombre Vicaria</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtnombrevic" name="txtnombrevic"
                       placeholder="Vicaria para la educacion...">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                <label>Nombre Proyecto</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="txtnombreproy"
                placeholder="Formacion de comunidades">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3 ">
                <label >Persona Responsable</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="txtpersonaresp" placeholder="Bill Gates">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3 " >
                <label>Solicitud Aporte</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="txtsolicitudapo" placeholder="Solicitud $">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3 ">
                <label>Año</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="txtaño" placeholder="2017" value="<?php echo date('Y')?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3 ">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Entrega Cuotas?</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rbtentregacuotas" id="rbtsi"
                               checked onclick="EntregaCuotaSi('divValorCuota')" value="si">
                        Si
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rbtentregacuotas" id="rbtno"
                               value="no" onclick="EntregaCuotasNo('divValorCuota')">
                        No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3" id="divValorCuota">
                <label>Valor Cuota</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtvalorcuota" name="txtvalorcuota" placeholder="Valor cuota">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-3 ">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="Boton" value="Guardar">
                <!--<a href="../Controller/ProjectoController.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">Guardar</a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

y mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
    class  ProyectoController
  {
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once "../Model/ProjectoModel.php";



    }

    function Guardar(){


        $proyecto = new ProyectoModelo();

        $proyecto->setIdVicarias('prueba1');
        $proyecto->setNombreProyecto('prueba1');
        $proyecto->setSolicitudAporte('prueba1');
        $proyecto->setAnoProyecto('prueba1');
        $proyecto->setPersonaResponsable('prueba1');
        $proyecto->GuardarProyecto();
        echo "test ok";


    }
 }
```

cuale es la manera de activar el metodo del controlador a traves de la vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, lo que necesita se llama enrutamiento aquí te dejo un articulo que te explica como hacerlo [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://www.weblantropia.com/2016/07/28/enrutamiento-urls-htaccess-php/), suerte.

Comment: Gracias! es lo que estaba buscando! me volvía loco ya!